# Using z transformation in a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using RetailRocket as my dataset. I assigned every event a value, view = 1, addtocart =2, transaction = 3. Now I want to use z-transformation to normalize the values. Unfortunately I got an error. Where is my mistake?

This is my z-transformation code:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42)
x = df[["visitorid", "itemid"]].values
#y = df["code"].values
y = df["code"].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()).values
# Assuming training on 90% of the data and validating on 10%.
train_indices = int(0.9 * df.shape[0])
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = (
    x[:train_indices],
    x[train_indices:],
    y[:train_indices],
    y[train_indices:],
)
print(y)
```

I found this formula for z-transformation with `numpy`:

```
X = (X - X.mean()) / X.std()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2712d78bf2a4> in <module>()
      2 x = df[["visitorid", "itemid"]].values
      3 #y = df["code"].values
----> 4 y = df["code"].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()).values
      5 # Assuming training on 90% of the data and validating on 10%.
      6 train_indices = int(0.9 * df.shape[0])

1 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-7-2712d78bf2a4> in <lambda>(x)
      2 x = df[["visitorid", "itemid"]].values
      3 #y = df["code"].values
----> 4 y = df["code"].apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()).values
      5 # Assuming training on 90% of the data and validating on 10%.
      6 train_indices = int(0.9 * df.shape[0])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `apply(lambda x: ...)`, `x` will simply be a single value. When you try to use `x.mean()` on that single value there will be an error.

Instead what you want to do is to use `mean` and `std` on the whole column. Using `apply`, this can be done as follows:

```
col = 'code'
df['z_score'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: (x - df[col].mean()) / df[col].std())
```

However, it is faster without `apply`:

```
df['z_score'] = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this:

```
y = (df["code"] - df["code"].mean() / df["code"].std().values
```

I like this method:(High-Performance, if your dataset has more than 15,000 rows)

```
df.eval('(code-code.mean())/code.std()')
```